# I am creating a player controller with a zooming system, but it is presenting some unexpected bugs

Tags: godot, gdscript, godot4

I can create the code and logic, and it works fine. However, the problem arises when my camera goes out of the range of the Node2d node; it loses control of the Camera2D controls, and I never expected this issue in Godot.

I highly recommend you watch this video as it can provide you with a better understanding of the issue.

Download link: https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/alor28.appspot.com/o/uploads%2FScreencast%202023-12-31%2018%3A02%3A34.mp4?alt=media&token=16769086-c2e0-494b-8336-d670468aa0f3

i want to fix this zoom issue i don't want this types of issue i don't think it come with my Camera controller script.
also here is my code if need

```
extends Camera2D

# Player reference
var player

# Camera settings
var default_zoom = Vector2(0.4, 0.4)   # Default zoom level
var camera_offset = Vector2(0, 0)      # Offset between player and camera
var follow_speed = 0.7                 # Speed of camera following
var zoom_speed = 0.2                   # Speed of zooming while moving
var zoom_step = 0.1                    # Zoom step when moving or jumping

# Track player's previous position to determine movement
var prev_player_position = Vector2.ZERO

func _ready():
    # Attempt to find the player node dynamically with a maximum number of attempts
    var max_attempts = 10
    var current_attempt = 0

    while player == null and current_attempt < max_attempts:
        player = get_node_or_null("/root/Game/Player")
        current_attempt += 1

        if player == null:
            print("Player node not found. Retrying in 1 second...")
            yield(get_tree().create_timer(1.0), "timeout")

    if player == null:
        print("Player node not found after multiple attempts.")

    # Set the initial zoom to the default value
    set_zoom(default_zoom)


func _process(_delta):
    # Rest of the code remains unchanged
    if player:
        var target_pos = player.global_position + camera_offset
        position = position.linear_interpolate(target_pos, follow_speed)
        clamp_to_scene_bounds()
        apply_zoom_step()


func clamp_to_scene_bounds():
    # Optionally, you can add code here to clamp the camera position to the scene bounds
    # For example:
    var viewport_rect = get_viewport_rect()
    position.x = clamp(position.x, viewport_rect.position.x, viewport_rect.size.x)
    position.y = clamp(position.y, viewport_rect.position.y, viewport_rect.size.y)

func apply_zoom_step():
    if player.global_position != prev_player_position:
        # Player is moving or jumping
        var distance_to_player = position.distance_to(player.position)
        var target_zoom = clamp(1.0 / (distance_to_player * zoom_speed), 0.5, 2.0)

        # Apply zoom step
        var new_zoom = Vector2(default_zoom.x * target_zoom, default_zoom.y * target_zoom)
        new_zoom = new_zoom.linear_interpolate(get_zoom(), zoom_step)
        set_zoom(new_zoom)

    # Update the previous player position for the next frame
    prev_player_position = player.global_position
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method `clamp_to_scene_bounds` makes no sense to me.

The code would be restricting the `Camera2D` to the `Viewport`... Which is the area you see, not the size of the scene. *Which I understand is hard to visualize because what you see is moving with the `Camera2D`.*

So that code would be preventing the `Camera2D` to reach the player when the player goes further from the origin than the size of the `Viewport`. And that results in a difference between the position of the `Camera2D` and the player that the `apply_zoom_step` takes as a cue to zoom.

If I'm correct, it should work correctly if you remove `clamp_to_scene_bounds`.